# Is there any way of creating a unique index which allows empty values in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a index with schema

```
{
   _id: "",
   name: ""
}
```

I want to make an index that supports names with unique values and permits adding data to databases when names have the value "" (empty string).

I tried using this:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   {name: 1}, 
   {unique: true, partialFilterExpression: {name: {$type: "string"}}}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty string `""` is still a **string**, so `partialFilterExpression: {name: {$type: "string"}}` will index this document.

In principle, it would be this one:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   {name: 1}, 
   {unique: true, partialFilterExpression: {name: {$ne: ""}}}
)
```

However, [partialFilterExpression](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/#create-a-partial-index) supports only these operators:

- equality expressions (i.e. field: value or using the `$eq` operator),
- `$exists`: true expression,
- `$gt`, `$gte`, `$lt`, `$lte` expressions,
- `$type` expressions,
- `$and` operator,
- `$or` operator,
- `$in` operator

Looks like, this is not possible. Only way would be to skip the attribute and use `{ partialFilterExpression: { name: { $exists: true } } }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string sort ordering to skip the empty string.

Have the partial filter require that name be type string and greater than "":

```
partialFilterExpression: {$and: [
                                  {name: {$type: "string"}},
                                  {name: {$gt: ""}}
                          ]}
```